# Reply Time Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm from Turkiye and my level is intermediate. I reply mails in 8 hours at work. My question is about time calculation.

**Conditions**

```
1. Our work starts at 09:00 and finishes at 18:00.
2. Mails must be replied in 8 hours.
3. Mails must be replied only between 09:00 and 18:00.
4. We don't work between 18:00 and the next day 09:00.
So these period doesn't count in the calculation. This is the most critical part also.
```

[My Excel File. I explained all conditions in the workbook.](http://zinzinzibidi.com/download/reply_time_issue.xlsx)

Comment: Can you show your expected answer to give us an idea what exactly do you want help with?

Comment: Column C is my expected answer. I explained it also at column D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we can break down your all condition to basically two categories. One, where (Mail Received Time + 8 Hours) is less than or equal to 18:00 Hrs, other is where it falls beyond 18:00 Hrs.

Use the formula in the Reply Deadline with formula column and drag it down to get the desired answer
`=IF((A7+"8:00"<=TIME(18,0,0)),MAX(A7,"9:00")+"8:00",MIN(A7,"18:00")+"23:00")`

Explanation

1. `IF` condition checks if the mail received time + 8:00 hrs is less than or equal to 18:00 hrs and returns a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value

Output: `=IF((FALSE),MAX(A7,"9:00")+"8:00",MIN(A7,"18:00")+"23:00")`

2. If `TRUE` the time is added by 8:00 hrs to give the deadline. `MAX` has been used to eliminate any mail received time that is before 9:00 Hrs as in 08:28 Hrs
3. If `FALSE` the time is added by 23:00 hrs. This is because 8:00 hrs is the normal deadline and remaining 15:00 hrs is accounted for time we don't work i;e from 18:00 Hrs to next day 9:00 Hrs. `MIN` is used to consider when the mail received time is less than 18:00 hrs.

Let me know if I can make it more clear.

**EDIT**

Here is my [sample file](https://www.sendspace.com/file/m3a55h) with solution formulas embedded.

Comment: Hi, 23 hour doesn't work. I calculated manually. So manuel values must be the same with formula values. Column C is manuel. Column B is formula. If you done, send me the same file that I linked. I wanna see your solution. You can use sendspace.com and upload here. Don't forget to give me download link.

Comment: @Mr.Zoidberg I've added my sample solution file using sendspace.com. Being naive to sendspace, I can only hope I have done it properly. Let me know if you've any other queries. And please mark it as answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I changed the true answer for you. Because yours has less code and more readable. Thanks so much! Greetings from Türkiye.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below formula,

`=IF(OR(A2<TIME(9,0,0),A2>TIME(18,0,0)),TIME(17,0,0),IF(A2+TIME(8,0,0)<=TIME(18,0,0),A2+TIME(8,0,0),A2+TIME(23,0,0)))`

[image]

This formula consists of 2 `IF` conditions. 
The first `IF` checks if the time falls in non-working hours (between 18:00 and 9:00). If so, the time is calculated as 17:00. If the time falls in the working range, the next `IF` condition adds 8:00 hours or 23:00 accordingly. (23:00 hours for overlapping period). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Shiva! Check my last post on this page. excelevator solved in a different way.

Comment: @Mr.Zoidberg Glad that it helped you!!

Answer (score 0):

excelevator solved the problem on reddit also.

https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/65l25n/reply_time_calculation_issue/